# how to get the first 2 files in multiple folder?

Tags: shell-script

My requirement is get the recent 2 files in sub folders.

We have 10 folders and each folder having 10 files, I need to get the recent 2 files in all 10 folders.

Please suggest script or command please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the 2 most recently modified regular files in each directory, with `zsh`:

```
dirs=(dir1 dir2...)
files=()

for dir ($dirs) files+=($dir/*(DN.om[1,2]))
(($#files)) && ls -ld -- $files
```

If you mean the 2 most recently modified regular files in all the directories, with GNU `find`, `xargs` and a recent GNU `sed`:

```
find dir1 dir2... -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
  sort -rzn | sed -z 's/[^:]*://;2q' | xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

Comment: Can you explain the DN.om[1,2] part? I've never seen that. Also, there is a typo in your answer: After `files+=(`, it should be `$dir`, and not `$dir1`.

Comment: Thanks @kira. See [here]( http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=om%5B1%5D)